# Where do thumbnail pictures come from on Mac?

Tags: macos, thumbnails, quicklook

[image]

As the picture shows above, when we use Pages, and open several pages, then on the "Show Recents" menu from the app icon on the dock, you can see the thumbnail. I designed my own app, which when I register a customised suffix file into the recent files, then my thumbnail will be like this.

[image]

How to make it more native like Pages?

[image]

I just want to get that static picture.

Answer (score 2):

Implement a [Quick Look generator](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/Quicklook_Programming_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html). That's a loadable code bundle that various OS components use to get thumbnails and previews for custom document types.

Comment: I have a quick look at that guide, my case is just get a overview of that file, I don't want to get a thumbnail or preview, I'm not concerned about that thing, I will update some more pictures to my question

Comment: That's exactly what a preview or thumbnail is. I'm not sure why you think it's different.

Comment: sorry, my fault, After I go through the quick look guide, I think you are right, I have one more thing to ask, how to register a new extension file, since when I test a generator in qlmanage, the log said, "returned error Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-10814 "kLSApplicationNotFoundErr: E.g. no application claims the file"". Another question is how to integrate this plugin into the app bundle.

Comment: You should have the generator target in the same project as your app. (Not necessary, but easier.) To integrate it into the bundle, view the app target's build phases. Add a Copy Files build phase and configure it to copy to Wrapper with path Library/QuickLook. Add the product of the generator target to that build phase. Also add the generator target itself to the app target's Target Dependencies. The generator should declare the document types it supports as described in the guide and so should the app, via the app target's Document Types on the Info tab.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. I think that would be great. And last question, for now. I get another solution which seems easier than this. I registered a customised file with extension, let's say ".aaa" and I give it a icon image in my app plist. Now I can see the image when I click "show recents". But there is one more difference with native app like pages. The File image is still a white paper nothing shows, but in preview, I can see my customised icon image. Why does this happen?